# Will my UI code be can be seen by end users if i have not purchased ext js 4 license or also along with the servlet logic code?

Tags: java, servlets, extjs, netbeans

I have develeped a web application developed with extjs 4 for UI and servlet for backend logic. I have not purchased any license from ext js and using the open source license. Many say my source code can be seen. My question is whether the end user can see the UI codings developed by ext js or my servlet codings too?

Comment: Your server-side source cannot be seen, but if you are using the open source license, you must release the source code of your application under a similar license. If you need to keep your source code private, you'll need to explore a different license. Regardless of whether you are using a commercial or open source license, however, your JS code will be visible to whoever wants to see it (assuming they have access to the application in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is whether the end user can see the UI codings developed
>   by ext js or my servlet codings too?

Servlet code runs on the server side. Unless someone has the access to your server, it is not possible to sneak in to your server side.

ExtJs is basically javascript and works on client side, hence it may be possible to see the code by a user.

From the [ExtJS FAQs](https://www.sencha.com/store/licensing-faq/)

> Ext JS and Ext GWT have commercial and open source versions. You may
>   download and use Ext JS and Ext GWT free of charge under the GNU
>   General Public License version 3 (GPL v3). However, you must comply
>   with the terms of the GPL v3 license. **Key terms for applications
>   written and distributed under the GPL v3 license require that you
>   release your source code to your users.**